# Query to Delete data from one on the basis of two other tables

Tags: sql-server

i am having a problem in making query. As i am new in learning sql. The problem is that i want to delete data from one table on the basis of two other table.
I have three tables of named Category, Book, Favorite List.

Table 1: Category contains CategoryID, CatagoryName.

Table 2: Book contains CategoryID, ISBN, Title

Table 3:  Favorite List contains ISBN, UserID.

If i delete any category from category table all the books along that specific category is deleted from Book table but i don't know how to delete those books from Favorite list table too.

Here is my query

```
 Delete FavrtISBN from FavouritList,Book,Catagory where Book.CatagoryID=Catagory.CatagoryID and Catagory.CatagoryID='CS001' and Book.ISBN=FavouritList.FavrtISBN;
```

Comment: I change my query and it work perfectly 
   "Delete F from FavouritList as F,Book,Catagory where Book.CatagoryID=Catagory.CatagoryID and Catagory.CatagoryID='"+Request["del"]+"' and Book.ISBN=F.FavrtISBN;"

Comment: You really should the "newer" style join instead of these older ones. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins  Also, it would do your code a mountain of good if you weren't scared to add some spaces.

Comment: ya sure thanks @Sean Lange